# Two different versions of requirejs on one web page

Tags: requirejs

I have an application where I'm using requirejs for my code. At the same time users of my app can add their own version of requirejs. To prevent conflicts of those two different versions of requirejs, is it sufficient to change keywords require/define/requirejs in my version of library? Or are there any additional steps to avoid this conflict?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like sufficient solution.

Comment: yes it does works. You have to change keywords and also data-main attribute to something custom like data-custom-main. Otherwise it will be loading a starting script from customers.

Comment: Previously it was 
<script type="text/javascript" src="require.js" data-main="script-main" />
I changed to 
<script type="text/javascript" src="mycustom-require.js" data-main="script-main" />   Is it correct ? Sorry i am new in require js

Comment: No. You have to change the data attribute. That's what is require.js looking for. <script type="text/javascript" src="require.js" data-custom-main="script-main" /> and also look for the require.js code for all the "data-main" and change it the to "data-custom-main".

Comment: So i need to replace data-main to data-custom-main in require.js library??
I am not sure if its a correct way ,  Do i need to change the code in library itself ?  I need to change this data-main keyword, everytime i update the requirejs version.

Comment: Yes, you have to change the require.js code and yes, you have to change it every time you update version. Maybe you can automate it somehow.